# How to make sense of `Zero-fill right shift` (`>>>`) in `d3.bisector` source code?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I could find [resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) on the operation of `Zero-fill right shift`, meaning how `15 >>> 2` return `3`.

I kind of understand how we get 3 from 15 by using this operation, but I have no idea the meaning and purpose of this operation.

Here I want to understand the logic of `d3.bisector`, but [`d3.bisector` source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/bisector.js) has the following line using `>>>`, I have absolutely no idea what it is for or intend to get:

```
var mid = lo + hi >>> 1;
```

According to the purpose of this function `d3.bisector`, variable `mid` seems to define the middle index of array `a`. If this is the case, then `lo + hi >>> 1` should be used to find the middle index. Based on this assumption I tried the following codes:

```
var a = 0 + 5 >>> 1;
console.log(a); // 2
var a = 0 + 6 >>> 1;
console.log(a); // 3
var a = 1 + 6 >>> 1;
console.log(a); //3
```

These examples seem to confirm the assumption. So, here are my questions

1. is `var mid = lo + hi >>> 1;` to find middle index of an array?
2. if it is, then why and how such operation could achieve it? at this stage, this code is like a black box, I know its purpose or what the outcome is for, but I understand no why, nor I can use `>>>` in any other cases.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bitwise operators >> and >>> are often used to perform fast integer division by 2.

For a positive number `a`, `a >>> n` equals `Math.trunc(a / Math.pow(2, n))`

The ordinary division operator is quite slow compared to bitwise shifting, which explains why it is often used whenever the divisor is a multiple of 2.

Beware: all bitwise operators convert their operands to 32 bit two-complements, thus reducing the effective range of a. Using >>> instead of >> guarantees that the result is always a positive number and returns the expected result for a in [0, 2^32-1]. This is desirable when working with arrays whose indices are always within this range.

Comment: Thank you @le_m, **perform fast intger division by 2**, this is very helpful!

Comment: also, to answer my second question, your code `a >>> n equals Math.trunc(a / Math.pow(2, n))` would indicate that `quarter = lo + hi >>> 2;` is to find the first quarter index. is it right?